# angular 2 routing url issue

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, url-parameters

this is my app.module.ts file.

```
 imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'subscriber', component: SubscriberComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
        //HttpModule
        FormsModule
    ]
```

inside my subscriber component i am getting a parameter from url inside ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {

    let id = '';
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        id = params['id'];
        if (id != '') {
            this.viewData(id);
        }
        console.log(id);
    });
}
```

which works fine but every time i use the url to get the param(xxx) e.g. http://localhost:60009/xxx
i am getting an error because the routing redirects to this url which obviously i dont have anythig linked. Any idea how to skip redirect from routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using route parameters, you'll need to specify them in your routing config.  You are trying to read parameter `id`, but `id` isn't specified in on the route in your config.  Try adding it to your config:

```
{ path: ':id', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

**EDIT**

Angular has both router parameters and query parameters.  Route params are specified in the route config like so:

```
{ path: ':id', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

You would access those in the component with:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(data => data['id']);
```

Then you also have query params.  These are not specified in the route config.  They look like this in the url:  `?id=something`  And you would access them in your component with:

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams =>  queryParams['id']);
```

The main difference is whether you use `params` or `queryParams` on the activated route and whether or not the params are specified in the route config.

Comment: if i define it like this how do i get it from the url?  something like ' http://localhost:60009/id=xxx'       ?

Comment: You'd get it from the url the same way you already are.  If it was `localhost:60009/id=xxx` then it would be a query parameter, not a route parameter.

Comment: is it possible to give me an example of a query parameter?